# Get the Number from a string

Tags: c#

I want to trim a string and get the number between special characters.
For example there is a `string BC/PO/88/2018` from it i want to get 88.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Splitting Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559121/c-sharp-splitting-strings)

Comment: show what you have done so far for this, also go through how to create [mcve].

Comment: try `"BC/PO/88/2018".Split('/')[2]` if the string format is same

Comment: _I want a packet of Tim Tams that never runs out_.  Sadly it is yet to happen

Comment: This question has been answered here before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575683/copy-part-of-a-string-to-another-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and extract a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of regular expression and extract number

```
Match match = Regex.Match("BC/PO/88/2018 f" , @"(\d+)");
if (match.Success) {
   return int.Parse(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

other way is you can do with the help of `String.Split` as suggested in comments if you are sure about string coming as input i.e. sure about format of string.

Comment: why there is - 1? its already accepted ans working solution...seems like some one doing with purpose ...hope SO people note that

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regular Expressions:

```
string strRegex = @"[A-Z]{2}/[A-Z]{2}/(?<MyNumber>[0-9]*)/[0-9]{4}";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"BC/PO/88/2018";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```